# Cant access property of resolved promise using await Promise.all()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

I have an array of images which I want to upload to MongoDB all at once:

```
images = [{ 
    id: 123,
    alt: "my image",
    buffer: <Buffer>,
    mimetype: "image/jpeg"
}]
```

I understand you should use `Promise.all()` for this, but I'm clueless about promises and was only able to string together the following where `Image` is my Mongoose Schema:

```
const uploaded_images = images.map(img => {
    return {
        id: img.id,
        promise: Image.create({
            image: { data: img.buffer, contentType: img.mimetype },
            alt: img.alt,
        })
    };
});

await Promise.all(uploaded_images.map(img => img.promise));
```

However, when I now try to access the `_id` property of the newly uploaded images, I am getting `undefined`

```
uploaded_images.forEach(img => {
    console.log(img.promise);        // gives Promise { { image: { data: new Binary(...), contentType: 'image/jpeg' }, alt: 'my image', _id: new ObjectId(...) } }
    console.log(img.promise._id);    // gives Undefined
})
```

How can I access the `_id` property?

After some more testing: Before the `await Promise.all()` line when I console log the array, I get  `[{ id: '013150333796129177', promise: Promise { <pending> } }]`. Then after that line when I console log it, I get `[{ id: '013150333796129177', promise: Promise { [Object] } }]`. Does that mean it is resolved? Why cant I access the Object?

Comment: What is the `id` property for if you're not using it to create your entities?

Comment: @Phil It is because these are images for a product which I will be creating after all this code. And I need to add the newly created images as foreign keys in that product schema and need to old id properties to map the right image to the right product properties

Comment: Is the property `buffer` or `Buffer`?

Comment: @Phil it is buffer with lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for all the `.promise` properties to resolve won't change them from promises to data; `.promise` will always be a Promise.

I think you want something more like this...

```js
const uploaded_images = await Promise.all(
  images.map(async ({ alt, buffer, id, mimetype }) => ({
    id,
    image: await Image.create({
      alt,
      image: { data: buffer, contentType: mimetype },
    }),
  }))
);

uploaded_images.forEach((img) => {
  console.log(img.id); // original id
  console.log(img.image._id); // Image entity id
});
```

The async function used in the `map()` callback will return a promise that resolves when the `Image.create()` completes. Using `Promise.all()` on this array of promises will complete once they've all resolved.

---

The above still inserts documents individually. If you want to batch-insert, you'd need to pass an array to [Image.insertMany()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-insertMany)

```js
const imageDocs = await Image.insertMany(
  images.map(({ alt, buffer, mimetype }) => ({
    alt,
    image: { data: buffer, contentType: mimeType },
  })),
  {
    ordered: true,
  }
);

const uploaded_images = imageDocs.map((image, i) => ({
  id: images[i].id,
  image,
}));
```

Note that combining the created docs with the `id` properties from the original array is a little more hacky now.

Comment: Does this upload each image to the database one at a time? It is acceptable if it is the only way, but I was hoping not to make too many request to my database